# Adding values to List

Tags: c#, list

Below is my code,

```
List<float?> LValues= new List<float?>();
List<float?> IValues= new List<float?>();
List<float?> BValues= new List<float?>();
List<object> data = new List<object>();

float? Value_Likelihood_fromList = 0;
float? Value_Impact_fromList = 0;
float? Value_Bubblesize_fromList = 0;

foreach (var item in Read_xml_for_childobjects_id.Root.Descendants("object"))
  {
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
    {
        Value_LValues_fromList = LValues.ElementAt(k);
        Value_IValues_fromList = IValues.ElementAt(k);
        Value_BValues_fromList = BValues.ElementAt(k);
        data.Add(new Data { x = Value_LValues_fromList, y = Value_IValues_fromList, z = Value_BValues_fromList });
        //  data.Add(data_content);
    } 
}
```

Here, my list contains 28 values in each like

```
LValues=[a1,a2,a3,a4....a28],
IValues=[b1,b2,b3...b28],
BValues=[c1,c2,c3...c28]
```

and my data list is getting in the form,

```
data=[[a1,b1,c2],[a2,b2,c2],[a3,b3,c3].....[a28,b28,c28]]
```

but I want to get four different data list as follows

```
data=[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2]....[a7,b7,c7]],
data=[[a8,b8,c8],[a9,b9,c9]....[a14,b14,c14]],
data=[[a15,b15,c15],[a16,b16,c16]....[a21,b21,c21]],
data=[[a22,b22,c22],[a23,b23,c23]....[a28,b28,c28]],
```

I know its very stupid of me to ask this logic question but I am facing real trouble to do this,any help will be greatly appreciated..

PLease note,I am populating the list by reading the xml string

for reference below is how I get values in list,this is for only one list,I do in same manner for other two as well,

```
for (int j = 0; j < value_BeforeOffset_l.Count; j++)
{
    var xmlAttributeCollection_for_period_BeforeOffset_L = value_BeforeOffset_l[j].Attributes;
    if (xmlAttributeCollection_for_period_BeforeOffset_L != null)
    {
        if (i == 0 && s == 0)
        {
            var periodid = xmlAttributeCollection_for_period_BeforeOffset_L["periodid"];
            xmlActions_Value_BeforeOffset_L[j] = periodid.Value;
            period_final_id = periodid.Value;
            try
            {
                period_name = ServiceClient.GetAttributeAsString(sessionId, periodid.Value, "name", "");
                if (period_Name.Count() <= 7)
                {
                    period_Name.Add(period_name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorValue = "Error found...Kindly Check Logs";
                logger.ErrorException("QPR Web Service ERROR", ex);
                return ErrorValue;
            }
        }
        if (s == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var action = xmlAttributeCollection_for_period_BeforeOffset_L["value"];  
                period_final_value = float.Parse(action.Value);
                LValues.Add(period_final_value);     
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                LValues.Add(null);
            }
        }
    }                         
}
```

--------Updated Question-----

```
foreach (var item in Read_xml_for_childobjects_id.Root.Descendants("object"))
  {
  for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
    {
        Value_LValues_fromList = LValues.ElementAt(k);
        Value_IValues_fromList = IValues.ElementAt(k);
        Value_BValues_fromList = BValues.ElementAt(k);
        data.Add(new Data { x = Value_LValues_fromList, y = Value_IValues_fromList, z = Value_BValues_fromList });
        //  data.Add(data_content);
    } 
  }
```

There are 4 items in Read_xml_for_childobjects_id, so if I need to make use of Following stmt,

```
  data[i] = new List<Data>();   // first initialize this List instance
```

According to Henk holtermen answer then how to do that..???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic approach:

```
//List<object> data = new List<object>();
List<Data>[] data = new List<Data>[4];    // why use <object> here ?

//...

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    data[i] = new List<Data>();  // first initialize this List instance 
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
        //... your current code
}
```

Comment: How I will add data to data list since I cannot get data.Add() now if accomplish d way u said..

Comment: and also instead of for loop for condition till 4 I have foreach loop  like this....foreach (var item in Read_xml_for_childobjects_id.Root.Descendants("object"))
                {....which gives 4 ids...since I am reading xml string..then how I will take the i value while initializing the list instance...can you please add and show me the data to data list and show...

Comment: You can call `data[i].Add(...)` . I don't understand the other question.