# To convert XElement into int value,

Tags: c#, linq, list, foreach, xelement

I have my loop for childobjects as follows,

```
List<float?> LValues = new List<float?>();
List<float?> IValues = new List<float?>();
List<float?> BValues = new List<float?>();
List<HMData>[] data = new List<HMData>[4];
float? Value_LfromList = 0;
float? Value_IfromList = 0;
float? Value_BfromList = 0;

foreach (var item in Read_xml_for_childobjects_id.Root.Descendants("object"))
{
    data[item] = new List<HMData>();  // Error occuring on this line
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
    {
        Value_LfromList = LValues.ElementAt(k);
        Value_IfromList = IValues.ElementAt(k);
        Value_BfromList = BValues.ElementAt(k);
        data[k].Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
    } 
}
```

on the following line,

```
data[item] = new List<HeatMapData>();
```

I get an error as follows,

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.XML.Linq.XElement' to 'int'.An Explicit conversion exist(are you missing a cast?),

-------Updated Question------

```
int indexer=0;
foreach (var item in Read_xml_for_childobjects_id.Root.Descendants("object"))
{
 data[indexer] = new List<HMData>();
 for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
 {
   Value_LromList = LValues.ElementAt(k);
   Value_IfromList = IValues.ElementAt(k);
   Value_BfromList = BValues.ElementAt(k);
   data[k].Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
  }    
  indexer++;
}
```

but I get error as object reference not set to instance of an object as soon as I enter into second for loop of k value, I have total 4 childobjects, where each childobjects populate each of the list by 7 elements..please check this link for detailed question..[Question with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905207/adding-values-to-list)
Having real tough time,will appreciate your help,Thank You,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the exception is self explanatory here that you are trying to pass an XElement to indexer where int is required. In order to pin-point it

```
data[item]
```

requires an **int** value in place of **item**. Which in your case is **XElement**. Hence the error.

Example (just example, don't use it): It should be something like

```
int indexer= 0;
data[indexer++] = new List<HeatMapData>();
```

Comment: I am having trouble with passing int to array index,can you please show me with eg how I can do this,

Comment: I know the error, I knew I need to pass the int value but don't know how to do that, even when I am trying to parse the item into int as data[int.Parse(item)]..I still get error as The best overloaded method match for int.Parse(item) has some invalid method arguments

Comment: you can not parse an XElement to int. Use some int value instead. What you are missing here is that ead_xml_for_childobjects_id.Root.Descendants("object") returns you XElement and not an int value.