# To add the element to List

Tags: c#, linq, list, foreach, xelement

Below is my code,

```
List<float?> LValues = new List<float?>();
List<float?> IValues = new List<float?>();
List<float?> BValues = new List<float?>();
List<HMData>[] data = new List<HMData>[4];
List<HMData>[] Data = new List<HMData>[7];
float? Value_LfromList = 0;
float? Value_IfromList = 0;
float? Value_BfromList = 0;
int indexer=0;

foreach (var item in Read_xml_for_childobjects_id.Root.Descendants("object"))
{
data[indexer] = new List<HMData>();  // Error occuring on this line
for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
  {
    Value_LfromList = LValues.ElementAt(k);
    Value_IfromList = IValues.ElementAt(k);
    Value_BfromList = BValues.ElementAt(k);
    Data[k].Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
  } 
  indexer++;
 }
```

As soon as I intend to add the element at Data list in following line,

```
Data[k].Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
```

I get an error as `Object reference not set to instant of object,`

I want output be as shown in following question link,
[Result required as shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905207/adding-values-to-list),

I have tried by lots of ways but could not make it,will really appreciate help if provided,Thanks.

Comment: First problem - never have two variables `data` and `Data`. That's a killer for readability. What's the *useful* difference between the two meant to be between those variables?

Comment: Actually..I was just trying trying to get it work done,there was initially only one data list but later on I created one more,my requirement is weird and it seems impossible, but then in coding everything is possible just might I am wrong somewhere in logic..can you please check the link given in above question for another question and just tell me what I am thinking to achieve his possible...

Comment: Well having code which is difficult to read isn't going to make it any easier to get the work done. Do *you* even know the difference between what the two variables are meant to represent?

Comment: ok...I totally agree with you and apologize for the mess..can you please follow this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905207/adding-values-to-list] and guide me...Please..

Comment: You've already got an answer on that question... and the update to it is very unclear.

Comment: I am not getting desired result..c..when I create List<HeatMapData>[] data = new List<HeatMapData>[4];..

Comment: then I get data list containing 4 count where each count should againg containe 7 data values, my other list like LValues,IValues and BValues in all contains 28 elements and I want first I want getting one common data list containing values as data={x=Lvalues[0],y=IValues[0],z=BValues[0]......x=Lvalues[28],y=IValues[28],z=BValues[28]} ,here 28 values are of 4 child objects and I need to pass them to highcharts to plot bubble chart bt this all values comes under one series, so problem is I need to plot for different data list for 4 different child objects so I can take them as different series

Comment: I hope my question is clear now,if not please let me know...just want to plot 4 data list and each data list containing 7 data values required the values are taken from there respective objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your code is a nightmare. You should really think about refactoring...
2. You have to initialize the lists within `Data` array.

   ```
   List<HMData>[] Data = new List<HMData>[7];
   for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
       Data[i] = new List<HMData>();
   ```
3. There are tons of other problems and questions that should be asked (like what's the difference between `data` and `Data`?, why are these array sized explicitly?). Without that knowledge every advice can be not enough to solve your real problem.

Comment: please follow this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905207/adding-values-to-list] and please tell me, is it possible to achieve the desired output...I have ended in nightmare achieving this output and I am extremely sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score -2):

you just need to declare the list as

```
List<HMData> Data = new List<HMData>();
```

and add new element to the list by

```
 Data.Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
```

Comment: That won't even compile - you're declaring an array variable, and then trying to assign it a plain `List<HMData>` reference.

Comment: Now you're assuming that the OP really doesn't want an array of lists... that's not clear to me based on the question.